# submit button doesn't disappear when submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a problem with a form on my website. I would like when you hit the submit button, the button disappears so the user can't click twice on it resulting in the form submitted twice. I have tried to change the function but I don't want to give up the loading icon showing. Can I add another function and add code to

```
onsubmit="showHide(); return true;"
```

? So that it executes 2 functions? Thanks in advance!

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=nl" async defer>
</script>
<script 
type="text/javascript">
function showHide() {
var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
if (div.style.display == 'none') {
div.style.display = '';
}
else {
div.style.display = 'none';
return false;
}
}
</script>

<style>
div.g-recaptcha {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 304px;
}
</style>

<form name="form2" method="POST" onsubmit="showHide(); return true;" action="/BESTANDEN/phps/JocanasNLsuggest.php">
Ideeën voor nieuwe films, TV-series, games of functies:<br><textarea class="input" name="comment" rows="5" cols="30" required></textarea><br><br>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="-----" data-theme="dark"></div>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="rect1"></div>
  <div class="rect2"></div>
  <div class="rect3"></div>
  <div class="rect4"></div>
  <div class="rect5"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="hidden_div" style="display:block">
<input type="submit" value="Voorstellen" name="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: This might be because there are two blocks with `hidden_div` id..Write a unique Id for submit button's div block to avoid name conflicts.

Comment: If I do that, I must write a new function code, right? So I must execute this code? So I need to add it to the onsubmit section. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide new Id to your submit button's div block and can write logic in the same function. There is no need for another function.

```
 <div id="hidden_div1" style="display:block">
<input type="submit" value="Voorstellen" name="submit">
</div>
```

and in your showHide() function:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("hidden_div1");
div1.style.display='none';
```

The working plunkr here:https://plnkr.co/edit/t18obhP0xxYPtZmf3Ppn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

id must be unique. Provide a  separate id for the button. Also you need to use prevent default behaviour otherwise the code to hide the button wont execute

```js
function showHide(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div_button-container");
  if (div.style.display == 'none') {
    div.style.display = '';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
div.g-recaptcha {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 304px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=nl" async defer>
</script>
<form name="form2" method="POST" onsubmit="showHide(event); return true;" action="/BESTANDEN/phps/JocanasNLsuggest.php">
  Ideeën voor nieuwe films, TV-series, games of functies:<br><textarea class="input" name="comment" rows="5" cols="30" required></textarea><br><br>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="-----" data-theme="dark"></div>

  <div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="rect1"></div>
      <div class="rect2"></div>
      <div class="rect3"></div>
      <div class="rect4"></div>
      <div class="rect5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hidden_div_button-container" style="display:block">
    <input type="submit" value="Voorstellen" name="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

An alternative option is to disable the button instead if hiding it